# why is torch::nonzero() very slow?

Tags: pytorch, torch, libtorch

I executed the code below.But nonzero() function is very slow (take 0.1 sec). what is wrong my code?

```
torch::Tensor a = torch::randn({30000, 80});
torch::Tensor b = a.select(1, 4) > 0.2;
const torch::Tensor c = torch::nonzero(b);
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not wrong. `torch::nonzero` has to check every entry in the tensor you give it, in this case `30000*80=2.4e+6`. That just takes a while.